# I get a crash with “Could not swizzle” when I launch EarlGrey tests

Tags: earlgrey

I get a crash with “Could not swizzle” when I launch EarlGrey tests, how do I avoid this?

Comment: Post us the code pls

Answer (score 2):

This means that EarlGrey is trying to swizzle a method that has been swizzled before: ensure that **only** the test target depends on EarlGrey.framework and the framework is embedded in the app under test. Since EarlGrey performs swizzling on in +load methods merely linking twice can cause this error at runtime.